# I can run Blender from Desktop but I can not run it from a USB Drive

Tags: usb-drive, chromebook, blender

Hello everyone I am running 14.04 on a Chromebook through Crouton.  I downloaded Blender from blender.org I did not use the command terminal.  I extracted it and I run it from the desktop, it works brilliantly everything is great.  As I am on a Chromebook however I want to cut corners and save space where I can on my very small SSD.  My goal is to put Blender on and run it from a USB Drive.  I got a fresh copy again from blender.org.  I was initially having difficulty extracting it because of symbolic links, I formatted my USB Drive too NTFS tried the extraction again and this time all of the files were moved to the USB Drive correctly to the best of my knowledge.  The issue comes when I try to open the Blender Executable in the USB Drive.  The screen shot I linked is what I am seeing.  I get a dialogue box that says:

Could not display "blender."

There is no application installed for "executable" files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

Yes/No

[Trying to run Blender from Flash Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrMWa.png)

I can still go back to and run the Blender I have on my Desktop.  Thank you.

Comment: The type of Chromebook is important, because most Ubuntu software is made for x86 processors, and some Chromebooks have ARM processors (which are not common for PCs and are usually used in phones and smaller devices such as the Raspberry Pi). ARM processors can only run software specifically compiled for ARM processors, meaning a lot of software will not run. It is sort of like how 64-bit software will fail to run on 32-bit CPUs, but different. **Also, make sure that in the file settings you checked the box marking it as an executable.**

Comment: This is an Intel Chromebook I am on.  After tinkering around I think that what I am running into is actually a permissions issue.  I just need to mount the USB drive with permission to execute a file.